# Did anybody use the constream (constrea.h) lib?

Tags: c++

Two years ago, I used the conio.h (actually conio2.h for Dev-C++) to create a console form interface. Now I want to make the same thing, but C++ std lib does not provide the needed functions and I don't want to use the old C conio lib.

I found some websites which highlights the constream lib, but I have no idea to use it on VS!

I tried just copying the header file into my project, but VS show several erros. I believe I am doing something wrong.

ps: i got this file: ftp://ftp.cs.technion.ac.il/pub/misc/baram/TC31/INCLUDE/CONSTREA.H

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are doing something wrong.  Trying to use C++ code that's 19 years old.  It depends on an old version of iostream, it has been removed from Visual Studio (and other compilers) about 10 years ago.  Trying to get this work is not worth your time.

You could use the [Win32 console functions instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had know idea that constream was dependent of an old version of iostream. I will try this other lib. I guess it has all the functions I need.